# how to catch harakiri in django

Tags: django, signals, uwsgi

I would like to catch "harakiri signal" in django application to log some info.

This code makes harakiri from uwsgi sources:

```
if (uwsgi.workers[i].pid > 0) {
    kill(uwsgi.workers[i].pid, SIGUSR2);
    // allow SIGUSR2 to be delivered
    sleep(1);
    kill(uwsgi.workers[i].pid, SIGKILL);
}
```

I have tried catch SIGUSR2 signal (views.py):

```
import signal

def signalhandler(signum, frame):
    print "!!! harakiri"
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger("log")
    logger.error("harakiri !!!!!!!")

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, signalhandler)
```

but it doesn't work. I haven't see logs in my code :-(